# How can I recreate the lasso contour plots?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to recreate a lasso contour plot, like either of these:

[image]

[image]

I've written this R code for it:

```
n1=60
n2=60
someData <- rep(0, 60*60)  
data = expand.grid(x=linspace(-3,3,n1),y=linspace(-3,3,n2))
lambda_v = c(10,10)
V_arr = rep(0,60*60)
count = 1
for (ii in 1:n1){
    for (jj in 1:n2){
            V_arr[count] = t(as.matrix(lambda_v))%*%as.matrix(c(abs(data$x[count]), abs(data$y[count])))
            count = count+1
    }
}
plot_ly(x=data$x,y=data$y,z=V_arr,type="contour")
```

which generates

[image]

So I've clearly got the right shape, but I don't know how to define the white regions, nor the OLS ellipses.

Comment: Well, first you need to calculate `s` from lambda: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190993/how-to-find-regression-coefficients-beta-in-ridge-regression